# How to create page detail in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem, sling, htl

I want to create a page detail of **product** containing the following information such as name, ID, type, status, quantity, description etc by AEM 6.1. But it seems difficult to me.

Assuming there is a table of product list. Once clicking the **Read One** link in a row, the detail page of the item will absolutely be rendered.

[image]

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this really depends on how your product details (ID, type, status, quantity, description, etc) are stored.

A good solution would be to create a new page component that reads an ID http parameter passed when clicking on the **READ ONE** button as an argument into the rendering of the new (PRODUCT DETAIL) page. 
so the all the buttons would look like this: www.mywebsite/products/productdetails?ID=**x** where **x** is the ID of the product in the given row when clicked.

Your new page component would have to have a code snippet similar to this:

```
<div id="product-detail-component" data-sly-use.product="com.mypackage.models.ProductModel">
 <ul>
    <li>${product.ID} </li>
    <li>${product.description}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And then you would need a new Sling Model class that can handle a http parameter

```
@Model({adaptables= Resource.class,SlingHttpServletRequest.class}) public class Product Model {

@PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
/*
1.retrieve HTTP parameter which is ID
2.access resourceResolver/resource to locate node containing product properties relative to resource location
*/
}
}
```

This is a very basic and not functional example, but I think it may give you a better direction.